# When the quadratic formula has square root of zero, how to proceed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Is there an easier way to solve the following equation?

$$x^2=2x-1$$

I think I know how to find $x$, using the quadratic formula:

I get

$$x^2-2x+1=0$$

then

$$x=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4})}2= \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{0}}2$$

but I don't know what $\sqrt{0}$ is. Is it $0$? If so, I would get $x=1$. Is that right?

The teacher said that $\sqrt{\phantom 0}$ is only for positives. Is $0$ positive?

Comment: $\sqrt 0 = 0$, so your root is $2/2 = 1$, (with multiplicity $2$.)

Comment: You teacher should have said that "you can only take the square root of a *non-negative* real number."  We know $0$ is not negative, so we can take the square root.

Comment: Okay thank you. Maybe she wanted to say positive AND zero but forgot zero. Is sqrt(0)=0 because 0^2=0? Like the way sqrt(2)^2=2?

Comment: i tried the $ like the others but not quite the same...

Comment: ok now i get it it is with {} not ()

Comment: Thanks Peter Phipps for the good format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square root function, in the reals, $\sqrt a$ is defined for all $a\geq 0$: that means the square root of a real number $a$ is defined strictly for all $a$ greater than *or equal to* $0$.

So your root becomes $\dfrac {2\pm 0}{2} = 1$. This root has multiplicity of two; indeed, $$x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x-1)^2 = (x-1)(x-1)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So my way was good also? You and Dr. Graubner seem to see the solution in a much simpler way by saying (x-1)^2. Why is this relevent? Why true?

Comment: Your solution was fine. If you can see how to factor a quadratic easily, do so.  But if not, you've always got the quadratic formula to use. The roots of your quadratic are those x-values that make the quadratic$ = 0$. Writing the function as $(x-1)^2$ shows us that $(x-1)^2 = 0 $ if and only if $(x-1) = 0,\iff x = 1$.

Comment: Ok I see thank you. i think factor is next in my course i will ask teacher

Comment: $x = a$ is a root, if and only if $(x - a)$ is a factor of the quadratic. (Note that when $x = a$, $(x - a) = a-a = 0$. By the zero product rule, if any one factor in a product of factors is zero, then the entire product is zero.

Answer (score 0):

it is equivalent to $$x^2-2x+1=0$$ and we get $$(x-1)^2=0$$

Comment: I appreciate your way. I will ask my teacher about it because I dont know for now.