# way to find sqrt

Tags: square-numbers

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065392/math-question-find-x) I asked what is $\sqrt{0}$ and learned that it is 0. I learned also that $\sqrt{2}^2=2$ in my class. Then I see $\sqrt{0}^2=0^2=0$. So in general to find $\sqrt{x}$ is it to find $y$ such that $y^2=x$?

Also i see it works for $\sqrt{4}=2$ because $\sqrt{4}^2=2^2=4$. So $\sqrt{4}$ is $y$ such that $y^2=4$.

Comment: Yes, it is the definition of square root.

Comment: Wow that link to my question is so cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $y = \sqrt{x}$ will satisfy $y^2 = x$.  For real numbers, as long as $x \geq 0$ then $x$ has a real square root.  The only thing you have to add to your explanation is that you actually find two solutions to $y^2 = x$ (except for $x=0$).

For example, as you say $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ but also $(-\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$.  This is why you will often see that when people solve $y^2 = x$ they will write $y = \pm \sqrt{x}$, meaning that $y$ could be either of those values and satisfy the equation.

To summarize, we choose to write $\sqrt{x}$ as the positive solution $y$ to $y^2=x$, for $x >0$.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a link between the square in $ax^2+bx+c$ and the $\pm$ in $(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$? Is it for the same reason?

Comment: Because I just realize that finding $\sqrt{x}$ is like $ay^2+by+c$ but with $a=1$, $b=0$ and $c=0$.

Comment: Does this make sence?

Comment: Yep.  If you look at a derivation of the quadratic formula, for example on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), you will see a point where they solve $(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}$, and when you take square roots at this point you introduce the ambiguity.

Comment: No it is $c=-x$ in fact.

Comment: Yes the formula gives $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$ so it works like your answer.